# Update a range if the source cell is not blank, otherwise skip to next

Tags: vba, excel

I can't seem to figure out one condition of my code.  I'm also a beginner at VBA. In short, I have a slicer on one worksheet that contains my filter values, and I have a range of 19 cells that can be updated with a drop down list I setup using data validation.

When a value is selected in ANY cell of the range on the source worksheet (source range is M8:M26), I need it to update the corresponding cell in a range of another workbook (which is not a continuous range like in the source workbook).  For example, M8 will update AB335 when the filter is on desk1, M9 will update AB358, etc...  I'm having the most trouble figuring out how to loop the update so if the first cell in the source range is blank, skip to the next and continue with the updates.

If the cell is blank, I also don't want it to override the destination range cell with a blank value, and so far that seems to work with my code.  I just can't get it to update if the values are updated in a random order on the source range.  Weird caveat is if I enter all of the values without skipping a cell, it will update fine.  How can I figure out how to move to the next cell and continue with the update if the previous cell had no selection?  Here's what I have for code so far:

```
      Sub UpdateRisk_Click()
Dim wksSource As Worksheet, wksDest As Worksheet
Dim strArray(0 To 18)    As String
Dim Arng            As Range
Dim Brng            As Range
Dim cell            As Range
Dim counter         As Long

Set wksSource = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("By Risk Pivot")
Set wksDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("(NEW) Full Data")
Set Arng = wksDest.Range("AB335,AB358,AB379,AB380,AB382,AB383,AB386,AB391,AB404,AB409,AB410,AB412,AB413,AB423,AB427,AB432,AB438,AB442,AB443,AB444")
Set Brng = wksDest.Range("AB109,AB130,AB151,AB152,AB155,AB157,AB159,AB166,AB178,AB185,AB186,AB187,AB188,AB193,AB197,AB199,AB204,AB206,AB208,AB209")

counter = 0

strArray(0) = wksSource.Range("M8")
strArray(1) = wksSource.Range("M9")
strArray(2) = wksSource.Range("M10")
strArray(3) = wksSource.Range("M11")
strArray(4) = wksSource.Range("M12")
strArray(5) = wksSource.Range("M13")
strArray(6) = wksSource.Range("M14")
strArray(7) = wksSource.Range("M15")
strArray(8) = wksSource.Range("M16")
strArray(9) = wksSource.Range("M17")
strArray(10) = wksSource.Range("M18")
strArray(11) = wksSource.Range("M19")
strArray(12) = wksSource.Range("M20")
strArray(13) = wksSource.Range("M21")
strArray(14) = wksSource.Range("M22")
strArray(15) = wksSource.Range("M23")
strArray(16) = wksSource.Range("M24")
strArray(17) = wksSource.Range("M25")
strArray(18) = wksSource.Range("M26")

For Each cell In Arng
    If (strArray(counter) <> "") And (ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Global_Desk1").SlicerItems("desk1").Selected = True) Then
        cell.Value = strArray(counter)
        counter = counter + 1
   End If
Next cell

For Each cell In Brng
If Not (strArray(counter) = "") And (ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Global_Desk1").SlicerItems("desk2").Selected = True) Then
    cell.Value = strArray(counter)
    counter = counter + 1
End If
Next cell

Call PivotTableRefresh

MsgBox "Updated Successfully"
End Sub
```

Comment: Try moving `counter = counter + 1` outside the `IF`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored your code a little bit:

```
Sub UpdateRisk_Click()
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Dim wksDest As Worksheet
Dim strArray(0 To 18) As String
Dim Arng As Range
Dim Brng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Integer

Set wksSource = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("By Risk Pivot")
Set wksDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("(NEW) Full Data")

Set Arng = wksDest.Range("AB335,AB358,AB379,AB380,AB382,AB383,AB386,AB391,AB404,AB409,AB410,AB412,AB413,AB423,AB427,AB432,AB438,AB442,AB443,AB444")
Set Brng = wksDest.Range("AB109,AB130,AB151,AB152,AB155,AB157,AB159,AB166,AB178,AB185,AB186,AB187,AB188,AB193,AB197,AB199,AB204,AB206,AB208,AB209")

For i = 0 To 18
    strArray(i) = wksSource.Range("M" & (i + 8))
Next i

If ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Global_Desk1").SlicerItems("desk1").Selected Then
    i = 0
    For Each cell In Arng
        If strArray(i) <> "" Then cell.Value = strArray(i)
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
End If

If ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Global_Desk1").SlicerItems("desk2").Selected Then
    i = 0
    For Each cell In Brng
        If strArray(i) <> "" Then cell.Value = strArray(i)
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
End If

Call PivotTableRefresh

MsgBox "Updated Successfully"

End Sub
```

A few notes:

1. double-check your wksDest assignment. It will work if the destination sheet is in the same workbook. If it's in a different book, your code won't work;
2. Your array contains 19 values, but your ranges have 20. They need to be in sync, otherwise you'll get a VBA error ("subscript out of range")

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Your format of the array makes much more sense than what I had as well.  Thank you!